# Override angular 3rd party directive name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, namespaces

Is there a good way to override existing directive names in my angular app?

Say 2 3rd party directives both use the name `grid`, how to avoid that they conflict?

Is it possible to register a directive anonymously? And require to give it a name in the config phase in my app?

Comment: Are you trying to use both directives, or just one, while the other is part of a larger required package?

Comment: It is a fictional example, but a problem I am worried about. But yes in the example I want to use both. And both are 3rd party. So forking and changing the name isn't something I want to do.